# how to link css and js in htmlpy

Tags: javascript, python, css

I am trying to use htmlpy 2 . i use the following code in .py file there is index files and some css files . i can render html but unable to link css to the html file. if i use absoulute path in html (D:/test/css.css) its working but when i use relative path its not working . In htmlpy documentation they said that we have to Set static_path and template_path .

> When using htmlPy.AppGUI, always set static_path and template_path
>   right after instantiating GUI. Set BASE_DIR variable as the absolute
>   path to the directory of the driver file and set static_path and
>   template_path with respect to BASE_DIR

```
import htmlPy
import os

app = htmlPy.AppGUI(title=u"htmlPy Quickstart", maximized=True , developer_mode=True)
BASE_DIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))


app.static_path = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static/")
app.template_path = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates/")
app.template = ("index.html", {"username": "htmlPy_user"})

app.start()
```

Kindly help me how can i link css and js files in htmlpy 2 .

Answer (score 1):

You got tu use Jinja 2 sintax, for example

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ 'estyle.css'|staticfile }}"/>
```

Just replace 'estyle.css' with your css path. I saw you especify your static path like "static" so got tu put your css file in there,  if your css file is in that directory just replace 'estyle.css' with your css file name, but if you have it inside other directory in the static directory like css you shuld replace it with 'css/css_file_name'.

And the same for javascripts.